# Best Approaches PHP - Redirects and Header Files

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

One common use of PHP is to output 'templates', such as a header, to give sites a consistent look and make updates easy through require or include commands. Another common task is to handle log-ins, and redirect users if their credentials are validated. However, these two common tasks can interfere with one another - required or include header templates often include output (such as a set of HTML navigation links), but this obviously interferes with redirecting using PHP headers.

This is an issue I have been encountering with increasing frequency. I have found workarounds (such as Javascript redirects, or detecting if a certain value, such as the one assigned to a login submit button, is set), but nothing particularly elegant.

What approach would you recommend for handling redirects when a file that generates output must be included at the top?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use output buffering. Meaning you can output content, but PHP will wait with actually sending the output allowing you to still set headers.

Some documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Most interesting will probaly be the function `ob_start`.